# Extract plain database from a large file based on binwalk results

Tags: binwalk

I want to extract a plain SQL database from a file which is used by a software (CTF). The target is a file with `.db` extension. The file itself doesn't have a signature and `file` command doesn't provide any information.

Here is `binwalk` results for it:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14325627      0xDA977B        MySQL MISAM index file Version 3
21565907      0x14911D3       MySQL ISAM index file Version 1
72246559      0x44E651F       Encrypted Hilink uImage firmware header
84112663      0x5037517       MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 4
118043401     0x7093309       Uncompressed Adobe Flash SWF file, Version 69, File size (header included) 43873325
179279624     0xAAF9708       PARity archive data - file number 20256
```

Based on `procmon` results, different offsets with different sizes from the database are read, not the whole database.
Here are few lines of the `ReadFile` call:

```
"6:43:19.2040892 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,424,896, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2047398 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,457,664, Length: 24,576, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2053113 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,519,104, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2056561 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,551,872, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2063946 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,584,640, Length: 24,576, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2068924 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,641,984, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2073310 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,674,752, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
"6:43:19.2077049 AM","phonenum.exe","7596","ReadFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\CTF\Phone Number Search\white\phonenum_search.db","SUCCESS","Offset: 9,707,520, Length: 32,768, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal"
```

Is there any chance that the .db file is not encrypted ?

Comment: Have you tried casual [SQLite CLI](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)?

Comment: As I said, the `.db` file itself isn't a known type. The result of using sqlite3 would be: Error: file is not a database